# Get bool value as string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having two scripts. I am using one script to change the bool variable of another script. What I want in my first script is to have the string as the boolean variable (to reference the bool in second script). How do I achieve this?

I want to achieve this because I am adding the first script to multiple gameObjects and each of these GOs have functionality to activate/deactivate certain bool from second script. I would like to provide the names for each bool in Script 1 from my inspector window.

```
public Script2 script2;
public string nameOfBool; 

void Start () {
       script2.nameOfBool= true; //Is there a way to do this?
    }
```

Script 2

```
public bool Bool_1; 
public bool Bool_2; 
public bool Bool_3;
```

Comment: why do you need that? You surely **can** do it, however chances are you don´t need it at all. Maybe some kind of dictionary or a switch better serves your actual needs. So please describe what you actually want to achieve here, not what you think the solution might be.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I will be adding the first script to multiple gameObjects and so each gameObject has different functionality to activate a bool. Which is why I wanted to see if there is a way to do this.

Comment: `[bool]` is a value type, it has no identity - not sure how you intend to "reference the bool in second script" with a stringified value of another. If you intend to use reflection to augment the value of a property by name at runtime, store it like: `nameof(ClassInScript2.Bool_1)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen unfortunately nameof() is not supported in Unity.

Comment: Store a lambda/delegate then? `Action updateBool2 = () => script2.Bool_2 = true;`

Comment: Have you looked at the dynamic keyword? It is not possible to invoke a string from a dynamic, but it might solve your problem. Another option is instead of providing a string, providing 2 lamdas setting the boolean field to true or false.

Comment: If you really need to invoke strings, you can take a look at Roslyn scripting.

Comment: Could you guys please provide an answer. I am still bit confused how to go about with this.

Comment: Why not using a `BitArray` or even simply a `bool[]` ? You could also use a `Dictionary<string, bool>` if you want named booleans. All of this should be easier and faster than using reflexion to dynamically access properties values from their names.

Comment: Dictionary sounds good. Although I do not have much experience with it which is why I was trying to achieve something from my own

Comment: Pretty similar question earlier this day: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65933372/dynamically-adding-list/65933507#65933507 .. just replace `List<int>` with `bool`

Comment: @derHugo I used Mathias's solution but I shall use yours as well in future. Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing a property by name is not trivial, I'd suggest you create lambdas for each at startup:

```
public class Script1
{
  public Script2 script2;
  public Action<bool> UpdateBool1;
  public Action<bool> UpdateBool2;
  public Action<bool> UpdateBool3;

  void StartUp()
  {
    UpdateBool1 = (newValue) => script2.Bool_1 = newValue;
    UpdateBool2 = (newValue) => script2.Bool_2 = newValue;
    UpdateBool3 = (newValue) => script2.Bool_3 = newValue;
  }
}
```

Then at runtime:

```
UpdateBool2(true);
```

---

If you want to associate each with a name, store them in a `Dictionary<string, Action<bool>>`:

```
public class Script1
{
  public Script2 script2;
  public Dictionary<string, Action<bool>> BoolUpdaters;

  void StartUp()
  {
    BoolUpdaters = new Dictionary<string, Action<bool>>
    {
      {"first", (newValue) => script2.Bool_1 = newValue}
      {"second", (newValue) => script2.Bool_2 = newValue}
      {"third", (newValue) => script2.Bool_3 = newValue}
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can invoke them based on a string value:

```
string targetBool = "first";
BoolUpdaters[targetBool](true);
```

---

If you want to generate the list of updaters based on their names (known in advance), you might save yourself some typing by generating the code with a simple PowerShell script:

```
param([string[]]$BoolNames)

$BoolNames.ForEach({
  '{{"{0}", (newValue) => script2.{0} = newValue}}' -f $_
})
```

Save to a `.ps1` file, launch PowerShell, and run the command `path\to\file.ps1 -BoolNames Bool_1,Bool_2,Bool_3,...`

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me what is ```newValue``` here and should I declare it as int/bool?

Comment: `newValue` is a `bool`, you can declare it if you want, but it's not necessary (compiler will infer from context that it's a `bool` since the lambda expression is a `Action<bool>`)

Comment: Thank you. I like your answer. I have one question. What if I have 20-30 bools from my second script. Do I have to declare each and every one of them inside StartUp()? Is there a way I can mention one ```{nameOfBool, (newValue) => script2.Bool_1 = newValue}``` and then I can give the name of the bool from my inspector window?

Comment: @Soxehe Do you know/have the list of field names in advance, or do you want to dynamically discover them based on `Script2`?

Comment: Yes I already know the bool names in Script 2. There are basically 25 bools in total. So my theory is that I can attach the first script to few gameObjects and then give the reference name of the bool for each of them. So that every gameObject have unique bool to change.

Comment: @Soxehe my personal preference would be to write a simple PowerShell script to generate those 25 lines of code :-)

Comment: Yes if it would have been a windows application. Unfortunately I am using Unity and it would be used for multiple platforms :D

Comment: @Soxehe You're the only person who needs to run the PowerShell script to generate the C# script, so that doesn't really matter :-)